Why Table Spool on MemoryOptimized table and how to suppress it?
I am in the middle of the road to achieving an optimized query for faster execution, or at least I hope so. I stumbled upon a pattern (it looks strange to me) in the execution plan, which seems to be responsible for around half of the execution time currently. I did a research on the topic and this is how I managed to optimize it so far.
But first the background. I need to do this fairly basic, although a bit nasty-looking select query:
select distinct a1.* from
(
    select distinct
    al.AL_ParentCode as Code,
    c.Code as ContrCode
    from #ALevels as al
    inner join ActiveContrForAddressees as c
    on al.AL_Val = c.MarketType
    and al.AL_Type = 1
    and al.AL_ParentCode = '91'
    inner join Dealer2Dealer as d2d
    on
    (
        d2d.DealerID = c.DealerID
        or d2d.DealerID = c.MerchandiserCode
        or d2d.DealerID = c.StrikerCode
    )
) as a1
inner join
(
    select distinct
    al.AL_ParentCode as Code,
    c.Code as ContrCode
    from #ALevels as al
    inner join ActiveContrForAddressees as c
    on al.AL_Type = 6
    and al.AL_ParentCode = '91'
    inner join Dealer2Dealer as d2d
    on al.AL_Val = d2d.ParentDealerID
    and
    (
        c.DealerID = d2d.DealerID
        or c.MerchandiserCode = d2d.DealerID
        or c.StrikerCode = d2d.DealerID
    )
) as a2
on a1.ContrCode = a2.ContrCode
inner join
(
    select distinct
    al.AL_ParentCode as Code,
    c.Code as ContrCode
    from #ALevels as al
    inner join ActiveContrForAddressees as c
    on al.AL_Val = c.ObjType
    and al.AL_Type = 9
    and al.AL_ParentCode = '91'
    inner join Dealer2Dealer as d2d
    on
    (
        d2d.DealerID = c.DealerID
        or d2d.DealerID = c.MerchandiserCode
        or d2d.DealerID = c.StrikerCode
    )
) as a3
on a2.ContrCode = a3.ContrCode
inner join
(
    select distinct
    al.AL_ParentCode as Code,
    c.Code as ContrCode
    from #ALevels as al
    inner join Dealer2Dealer as d2d
    on al.AL_Val = d2d.ParentDealerType
    and al.AL_Type = 12
    inner join ActiveContrForAddressees as c
    on
    (
        d2d.DealerID = c.DealerID
        or d2d.DealerID = c.MerchandiserCode
        or d2d.DealerID = c.StrikerCode
    )
    and al.AL_ParentCode = '91'
) as a4
on a3.ContrCode = a4.ContrCode

Table #ALevels is populated from a normal table in advance, in a separate query.
-- this index is created after the table is populated:
create nonclustered index idx_ALevels
on #ALevels (
    AL_ParentCode, AL_Type, AL_Val
) include (AL_ParentType)

The definition of table ActiveContrForAddressees is this:
create table ActiveContrForAddressees (
    Code nvarchar(25) not null primary key nonclustered hash with (bucket_count = 150000),
    DealerID nchar(10) null,
    MerchandiserCode nvarchar(20) null,
    StrikerCode nvarchar(255) null,
    MarketType nvarchar(20) null,
    CustomerType nvarchar(20) null,
    CustSubClass nvarchar(20) null,
    CustClass nvarchar(20) null,
    Seasonal nvarchar(20) null,
    ObjType nvarchar(20) null,
    RegionCode nvarchar(60) null,
    InternalCategory int null,
    Chain nvarchar(100) null,
    index idx_ACFA nonclustered (
        Code, DealerID, MerchandiserCode, StrikerCode,
        MarketType, CustomerType, CustSubClass, CustClass,
        Seasonal, ObjType, RegionCode, InternalCategory, Chain
    )
) with (
    memory_optimized = on
)

It gets refreshed by the following procedure every time the data in the normal table changes:
create procedure RefreshActiveContr @contrCode nvarchar(25) = null
as
begin

    insert into Objects (O_Type) values ('RefreshActiveContrSync')

    --truncate table ActiveContrForAddressees
    --The statement 'TRUNCATE TABLE' is not supported with memory optimized tables.
    delete from ActiveContrForAddressees
    where coalesce(@contrCode, '') = ''
    or Code = @contrCode

    insert into ActiveContrForAddressees
    select Code, DealerID, MerchandiserCode, StrikerCode,
    MarketType, CustomerType, CustSubClass, CustClass,
    Seasonal, ObjType, RegionCode, InternalCategory, Chain
    from Contragent
    where coalesce(Distributor, 0) != 1
    and coalesce(Active, 0) > 0
    and coalesce(blocked, '') != '1'
    and
    (
        coalesce(@contrCode, '') = ''
        or Code = @contrCode
    )

    -- https://key2consulting.com/incorrect-indexing-can-slow-down-memory-optimized-tables/
    update statistics ActiveContrForAddressees with norecompute, fullscan

    delete from Objects where O_Type = 'RefreshActiveContrSync'

end

That 'RefreshActiveContrSync' thing is a synchronizing flag, which is checked and the select query is allowed to execute only if it is missing.
The definition of table Dealer2Dealer is this:
-- https://www.sqlshack.com/memory-optimized-table-variables-in-sql-server/
-- https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/improving-temp-table-and-table-variable-performance-using-memory/ba-p/384697
-- https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3104/determine-bucketcount-for-hash-indexes-for-sql-server-memory-optimized-tables/
-- https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3099/understanding-sql-server-memoryoptimized-tables-hash-indexes/
-- Clustered indexes, which are the default for primary keys, are not supported with memory optimized tables. Specify a NONCLUSTERED index instead.
create table Dealer2Dealer (
    ParentDealerID nvarchar(255) not null,
    ParentDealerType nvarchar(255) null,
    DealerID nvarchar(255) not null,
    primary key nonclustered /*hash*/ (DealerID, ParentDealerID)
    --with (bucket_count = 1024)
) with (
    memory_optimized = on
)

It gets refreshed by a similar procedure to the other one, which refreshes ActiveContrForAddressees table:
--truncate table Dealer2Dealer
--The statement 'TRUNCATE TABLE' is not supported with memory optimized tables.
delete from Dealer2Dealer

--a couple of insert queries...

-- https://key2consulting.com/incorrect-indexing-can-slow-down-memory-optimized-tables/
update statistics Dealer2Dealer with norecompute, fullscan

And now the interesting part - the execution plan and times, shown in SQL Server Management Studio:

And the execution plan itself:



Here you can see that all other operators execute in a matter of seconds:

Even the operators on the branch where the Table Spool is positioned:

Is there a way to optimize this query?
You may ask me why don't I use table variables of certain memory optimized type. I tried with table variables, but SQL Server complained about the fact that the table variable is out of the scope of the exec() or at least this is the conclusion I made, after it complained like "Must declare the table variable @temp"
The problem is that this query is built as a string and exec()-ed after that. Actually, it is a procedure, which builds several such query strings and executes them one after another, based on the tables #ALevels, ActiveContrForAddressees and Dealer2Dealer and a couple of other ones. It inserts the result from every query into another temporary table #Results and finally selects from that table. Thus, I decided not to create the suggested index, because the constructed query may include another column from table ActiveContrForAddressees, based on a very specific logic, and it once said that I cannot create more than 8 (if I remember correctly) indexes on a memory optimized table.
Edit: Thanks to @siggemannen, here is the whole execution plan. I reordered the part of the query 'a2' for type = 6 and it now looks like this (execution plan is from that new query):
inner join
(   
    -- адресиране по Код на ТП
    select distinct
    al.AL_ParentCode as Code,
    c.Code as ContrCode
    from #ALevels as al
    inner join Dealer2Dealer as d2d
    on al.AL_Val = d2d.ParentDealerID
    and al.AL_Type = 6
    and al.AL_ParentCode = '91'
    inner join ActiveContrForAddressees as c
    on
    (
        c.DealerID = d2d.DealerID
        or c.MerchandiserCode = d2d.DealerID
        or c.StrikerCode = d2d.DealerID
    )
) as a2

Here execution time is 10:11.

inner join ActiveContrForAddressees as c on al.AL_Type = 6 and al.AL_ParentCode = '91' aren't you missing the join against AL = c here? Also, why the distincts everywhere? Try formatting query before posting perhaps

Thank you for pointing this out. The idea is to take all active contragents related to all active dealers whose parent is among certain selected values in al for Type = 6. I think I could try to rewrite it like al join d2d join c so that every join has at least one '=' with both sides participating. I will keep you posted on that. I tried and tested with distinct only at a1.* from, but performance degrades significantly. I will edit question with better formatting, I do apologize for that!

if you don't need dealer data, you should convert the dealer joins to EXISTS. This should simplify your queries as well. ALso, INNER JOIN without conditions is just a cross join. Also, use https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ to paste the actual query plan so it's possible to analyze it properly

Thank you @siggemannen for your quick comments. I actually used exists while optimizing but for a different parameter of the procedure with exec(). I will try with exists here as well. Thank you for your link. I will include a link to the plan in the question.
